# Lost Permissions Can't Delete Folder

Tags: finder, permission, macos

I accidentally ran a PHP script that creates a directory with permissions 0777 and I am now unable to delete this directory. Any help to delete it would be appreciated, I have inserted a picture of the directory info below.

[image: directory info]

Comment: Please open Terminal, type `ls -dl `, drag&drop the parent folder of the one you want to delete onto Terminal, press Enter and add the Terminal output to the question

Answer (score 1):

If you're on an admin account, you should be able to click the lock, supply password, then click the + sign & add yourself as read/write.

If it won't let you do that, then try on the next folder up the hierarchy, setting permissions to at least add yourself as read & write, then click the 'gearbox' icon & 'apply to all enclosed items'.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. When applying to all enclosed items, nothing changes. When attempting to add myself I receive the same "you do not have permissions" message.

Comment: Sorry, then I'm completely stumped - 0777 should already be "rwx perms for everyone"

Comment: The permissions on the containing directory are what matter, not the permissions on the object you're trying to remove.

Comment: @MarcWilson - I'd thought that was implicit - but looking back it may not in fact be as clear as I'd thought - will amend.

Comment: This whole .../lampp/htdocs/uploads hierarchy seems to have bogus permissions... why would ONLY daemon have r/w there? The answer to @nohillside 's request will be interesting.